# Build Short cut in Mac Os Terminal

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to build a shortcut to run a python code. This code was built my developer who is now missing in action. I'm not able to write code in Mac OS terminal. In any case, I have two pythons files in the folder proofs. When I hit jj on the terminal it runs the code 5.7.16. I thought if I changed the first line from

FPTH="/Users/robertford/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/Proofs/5.7.16.py"

to

FPTH="/Users/robertford/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/Proofs/prove.py"

then the short cut would run the "prove" file but it doesn't. It continues to run the 5.7.16 file. So I'm trying to build a second short cut where if I hit kk then it runs the prove file located in the proofs folder. Any help would be appreciated. Don't worry about the stuff where it says excel, MySQL and django. That's not important.

```
    FPTH="/Users/robertford/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/Proofs/prove.py"
        vmysql=$(grep "mysql =" $FPTH | cut -d'=' -f2)
vexcel=$(grep “excel =" $FPTH | cut -d'=' -f2)
echo $vexcel
echo $vmysql
if [ "$vexcel" == "True" ] ; then
echo "Excel"
elif [ "$vmysql" = "True" ] 
then
echo "Mysql"
else
echo "Django"
fi
if [ "$vexcel" = "True" ] ; then
echo "Excel is set”
python $FPTH
elif [ "$vmysql" = "True" ] 
then
echo "Mysql is set”
python $FPTH
else
echo “Django is set”
cd /dUsers/robertford/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2
python manage.py runserver
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly you are trying to get `/Users/robertford/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/Proofs/prove.py` to execute by typing `kk` into your Terminal?

You could do that by adding an alias to your `.bashrc`.

So:

1. In your Terminal type: `nano ~/.bashrc`
2. Add the following line: `alias kk='python /Users/robertford/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/Proofs/prove.py'`
3. Press `ctrl + x`
4. Type `Y` and hit enter (enter might not even be necessary).
5. Be sure to source your bashrc. Type into Terminal: `source ~/.baschrc`

Done. Typing `kk` in Terminal now launches the script.